# Two themes for two tabulator inside one project

Tags: tabulator

I have a application, where i have used tabulator for multiple functionalities. Im having tow tables, in one application I would like to have two themes for those two tables. How do i implement this ? 
Please assist me.
Thanks
Ajith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had two tables ***#table1*** and ***#table2*** you would need to alter the CSS file for each of the theme and replace the ***.tabulator*** selectors with the table id or class, eg:

```css
.tabulator .tabulator-header
```

Would become:

```css
#table1 .tabulator-header
```